# Disable SSL check for install files action

Tags: java, ssl, install4j

The "Install files" action is missing the option "accept all SSL certificates" (like other server communication related actions support) for the case that the installer relies on downloadable data files (installer data files marked as downloadable in a media file).

Is there a possibility to disable the SSL check elsewhere or is it necessary to currently resort to other means (add keystore with certificate, write script to disable SSL checks, ...) for testing purposes in that actions case (tested with Install4j v7.0.10)?

Comment: Your question is kind of unclear, kindly edit it and add more details to it. Explain things you have tried and what exactly is the issue.

Comment: @Fennec I updated the question, hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to ej-technologies, the missing option is an oversight. Is likley do be added with the next version.